# Android не понятная ошибка

Tags: android, view

Не могу разобраться с ошибкой (приходит в fabric.io) проявляется на Android 5, на моем устройстве все работает нормально(немогу воспроизвести)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
bitmap size exceeds 32 bits
Raw Text
android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate (Bitmap.java)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:812)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:789)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:756)
android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState
.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded (VectorDrawable.java:713)
android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw (VectorDrawable.java:280)
android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode (View.java:15766)
android.view.View.drawBackground (View.java:15712)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15479)
android.view.SurfaceView.draw (SurfaceView.java:385)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14384)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15204)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3532)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3325)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14376)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15204)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3532)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3325)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15507)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14384)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15204)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3532)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3325)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14376)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15204)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3532)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3325)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14376)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15204)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:3532)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:3325)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchDraw
(PhoneWindow.java:2782)
android.view.View.draw (View.java:15507)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw (FrameLayout.java:658)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw
(PhoneWindow.java:2761)
android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:14384)
android.view.View.getDisplayList (View.java:14413)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList
(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList 
(ThreadedRenderer.java:285)
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:324)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:2915)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2729)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2343)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1274)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6607)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:800)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:603)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:572)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run 
(Choreographer.java:786)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5624)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:959)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас размер картинки после скейла не влезает в 32 бита. Вы при создание `Bitmap` какой density передаёте?

Скажем:

```
размер картинки  = 2048^2       = 4194304
если 32 бита на пиксель = 4194304 * 32 = 134217728
```

То передав, к примеру, 460, получим:

```
134217728 * 460 = 61740154880
```

что больше, чем `2^31 -1 = 2147483647`.